# TypeScript Error::Type '{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState; }' is not assignable to type '{ auth: never; error: never; }'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to set up my first project using React and Typescript, but I'm getting this error in my rootReducer:

```
Type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ auth: never; error: never; }>, IRegisterUserAction | IAuthenticateUserAction | LogoutAction | ConfirmAccountAction | ISetErrorAction | IHideErrorAction>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState; }, AnyAction>'.
```

Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type '{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ auth: never; error: never; }> | undefined'.
Type '{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState; }' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ auth: never; error: never; }>'.
Type '{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState; }' is not assignable to type '{ auth: never; error: never; }'.ts(2322)

**My rootReducer.ts:**

```
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,};

export const appReducers: Reducer<{ auth: IAuthState; error: IErrorState }> = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    error: errorReducer,});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof appReducers>;

const rootReducer = (state: CombinedState<RootState> | undefined, action: AuthActionTypes) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
        state = undefined;
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    return appReducers(state, action);};

export const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

**My authReducer.ts:**

```
export const initialState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    username: null,
    email: null,
    role: null,
    profileImage: null,};

const authReducer: Reducer<IAuthState, AuthActionTypes> = (state = initialState, action): IAuthState => {
switch (action.type) {
    case AUTHENTICATE_USER: {
        return {
            ...state,
            loggedIn: true,
            username: action.payload.username || null,
            email: action.payload.email || null,
            role: action.payload.role || null,
            profileImage: action.payload.profileImage || null,
        };
    }
    default:
        return state;
}};
export default authReducer;
```

**My errorReducer.ts:**

```
export const initialState = {
    error: null,
    validationErrors: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
    },
};

const errorReducer: Reducer<IErrorState, ErrorActionTypes> = (state = initialState, action): IErrorState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ERROR: {
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload.error || null,
            validationErrors: {
                username: action.payload.validationErrors.username || null,
                email: action.payload.validationErrors.email || null,
                password: action.payload.validationErrors.password || null
            }
        };
    }
    default:
        return state;
}};
export default errorReducer;
```

**My store.ts:**

```
export type AppState = {
    auth: IAuthState;
    error: IErrorState;
};
const initialState: AppState = {
    auth: authInitialState,
    error: errorInitialState
};

const middlewares = [thunk];

const configureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState, 
         composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
    return store;
}

const store = configureStore();
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

**My authTypes.ts:**

```
export const REGISTER_USER = 'REGISTER_USER';
export const AUTHENTICATE_USER = 'AUTHENTICATE_USER';
export const CONFIRM_ACCOUNT = 'CONFIRM_ACCOUNT';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

export type UserRegisterState = {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    passwordConfirm: string;
};

export type UserLoginState = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
};

export interface IRegisterUserAction extends Action<typeof REGISTER_USER> {
    type: typeof REGISTER_USER;
}

export interface IAuthenticateUserAction extends Action<typeof AUTHENTICATE_USER> {
    type: typeof AUTHENTICATE_USER;
    payload: IAuthState;
}

export interface LogoutAction extends Action<typeof LOGOUT> {
    type: typeof LOGOUT;
}

export interface ConfirmAccountAction extends Action<typeof CONFIRM_ACCOUNT> {
    type: typeof CONFIRM_ACCOUNT;
}

export type AuthActionTypes = IAuthenticateUserAction | LogoutAction | ConfirmAccountAction 
    | IRegisterUserAction;
```

**My errorTypes.ts:**

```
export const SET_ERROR = 'SET_ERROR';
export const HIDE_ERROR = 'HIDE_ERROR';

export interface ISetErrorAction extends Action<typeof SET_ERROR> {
    type: typeof SET_ERROR;
    payload: IErrorState;
}

export interface IHideErrorAction extends Action<typeof HIDE_ERROR> {
    type: typeof HIDE_ERROR;
}

export type ErrorActionTypes = ISetErrorAction | IHideErrorAction;
```

**My authActions.ts:**

```
export const registerUser: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<
    Promise<void>,
    RootState,
    UserRegisterState,
    IRegisterUserAction
>> = (userData: UserRegisterState) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
        await signUpUser(userData);
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_ERROR,
            payload: {
                error: error.response.data.message,
                validationErrors: error.response.data.validationErrors,
            },
       });
    }
};

export const authenticateUser: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<
    Promise<void>,
    RootState,
    UserRegisterState,
    IAuthenticateUserAction
>> = (userData: UserLoginState) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
        const user = await signInUser(userData);
        dispatch({
            type: AUTHENTICATE_USER,
            payload: user.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_ERROR,
            payload: {
                error: error.response.data.message,
                validationErrors: error.response.data.validationErrors,
            },
        });
    }
};

export const forgotUserPassword: ActionCreator<ThunkAction<
    Promise<void>,
    RootState,
    { userEmail: string },
    IAuthenticateUserAction
>> = (userEmail: string) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
        await forgotPassword(userEmail);
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_ERROR,
            payload: {
                error: error.response.data.message,
                validationErrors: error.response.data.validationErrors,
            },
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Error

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
        state = undefined;
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    return appReducers(state, action);
};
```

In the "logout" branch of this function, you set the state to `undefined` which you should not do because the **state should never by mutated directly**.  A reducer should return a new copy of the state.

I thought at first that you were returning nothing here.  I see now that you are setting state to `undefined` so that you can revert to the initial state.  Calling `appReducers` with `undefined` is okay, but you can't mutate the state in order to do so.  Try something like this:

```
const rootReducer: RootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
        localStorage.clear();
        return appReducers(undefined, action);
    }
    return appReducers(state, action);
};
```

### Type Suggestions

You have definitions for `type AppState` in your `store.ts` and `type RootState` in `rootReducer.ts` which are the same thing.  This isn't technically a problem now since the values match, but you want one canonical definition in one place.  That place should be the `rootReducer.ts` file because it's good practice to avoid circular imports, so we don't want the reducer to import from the store when the store already imports from the reducer.

Your `rootReducer` types the action as `AuthActionTypes` when it needs to also include error actions.  This is potentially a source of errors, but the current error is about state rather than actions.

Your types should look something like this:

```
export interface RootState {
  auth: IAuthState;
  error: IErrorState;
};

export type RootAction = AuthActionTypes | ErrorActionTypes;

export type RootReducer = Reducer<RootState, RootAction>

export const appReducers: RootReducer = ....

const rootReducer: RootReducer = (state, action) => {...};
```

With the reducer functions, you can either add a `RootReducer` type to the function itself or you can add types to the arguments and the return, but you don't need to do both.

note: when I hover over `state` on a function with `RootReducer` type, I am seeing `state: RootState` with no mention of it being possibly `undefined`.  I don't know why this is because the definition of `Reducer` is clear that state can be of the specified type or `undefined` (`type Reducer<S = any, A extends Action<any> = AnyAction> = (state: S | undefined, action: A) => S`)